# Add custom build steps to bdist

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, setup.py

It's possible to add build steps to `sdist` using the `cmdclass` argument to setup, E.g.,

```
# ./setup.py
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.sdist import sdist

class CustomSdistCommand(sdist):
    def run(self):
        # Do some preprocessing...
        super().run()

setup(
    # ...
    cmdclass={
        'sdist': CustomSdistCommand,
    }
)
```

Is it possible to do the same thing when using bdist?